# Bidding agent using node.js for RTBkit

Tags: node.js, rtbkit

With the RTBkit real-time-bidding kit for advertising, you can write your own agents in C++. But it also says you can write agents in node.js.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [wiki page](https://github.com/rtbkit/rtbkit/wiki/Nodejs-bidding-agents) describes exactly what you are trying to do. Did you try to follow the explanations ?

RTBKit also contains [an example](https://github.com/datacratic/rtbkit/blob/master/rtbkit/examples/nodeagents/nodebidagent.js) of a bidding agent written in Node.js. I think that both the wiki page and the example should be a good start and you should quickly be able to write your bidding agent in Node.js

Finally, note that RTBKit has a public [mailiing list](https://groups.google.com/a/rtbkit.org/forum/#!forum/discuss) for all the questions you could have. The list is quite active and the questions generaly find a fast answer. That might also help you if you start playing with RTBKit.

Enjoy !